# Forced to add JRE System Library to android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

On one machine my android library builds and runs fine. On another, with identical build path it would not build until I added JRE System Runtime.

Why might this be?

Comment: are you sure both the jre library paths for the machines are identical. And with that you should also see if the `android sdk` is placed identical to the other machine and machines should be having same OS's `32 bit or 64 bit`

Comment: ah ha. that is it. one is 32 bit machine one is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution should be somewhere in these :**

- Make sure both the jre library paths for the machines are identical.
- And with that you should also see if the android sdk is placed
  identical to the other machine
- And machines should be having same OS's 32 bit or 64 bit